# how to add more products in single order

Tags: javascript, php

I have a page book_order.php...when i fill details and after submit, all details are saved in a table order_management. What I want is once after submission, I need  a popup asking "do u want to add/book more products?" if press yes...that order_id is remembered and next booking must be done on the same order_id...how can i do this....?

i am saving the data in a table "order_management"  where i defined order_id as auto incremented field.. my question is once after i remembered the order_id for the next transaction...how can i insert it into the table?

```
    <?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
extract($_POST);

$order_date=date("Y-m-d");

$sql=mysql_query("select sku,quantity_in_stock,sold_quantity,crdate from stock_info where product_name = '$prod'");
$array=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$sku = $array[0];
$qis = $array[1];
$sold_quan = $array[2];
$crdate = $array[3];

$sql2=mysql_query("INSERT INTO order_management(order_date,brand,product,price,customer_name,phone_number,email,address,quantity,channel,courier,order_status,sku)
VALUES
('$order_date','$brand','$prod','$pri','$customername','$phonenumber', '$email','$address','$quantity','$channel','$courier','booked','$sku')");



if($sql2)
{
echo "<div class='da-message success'>Successfully Booked Your Order</div>"; 

}
else 
{
die(mysql_error());
}


$quantity_left = $qis - $quantity;
$sold_quan = $sold_quan + $quantity;

$diff_in_days = (strtotime($order_date) - strtotime($crdate))/(60 * 60 * 24);
$expctd_stock=round((7*$quantity_left)/$diff_in_days);
//echo $expctd_stock;



$sql3 =mysql_query("UPDATE stock_info SET quantity_in_stock = '$quantity_left',last_sold_date='$order_date', sold_quantity='$sold_quan', expected_stock='$expctd_stock' WHERE sku='$sku'");
/*$sql3 = mysql_query("update order_management set sku='$sku' where order_date=''");*/

}
?>

<form id="da-ex-validate1" class="da-form" method="post" action="">


                                           <div class="da-form-row">
                                         <label>Brand<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                <div class="da-form-item small">
                                                    <!--<input type="text" name="brand"  id="brand" class="required" value=""/>-->
                                                    <select name="brand" id="brand" onChange="retrievedata(this.value)">
                                                    <option value="">--- select brand ---</option>
                                                    <?php
                                                    $ord=mysql_query("select * from brand_info");

                                                    while($ord1=mysql_fetch_array($ord))
                                                    {

                                                    ?>  
                                                       <option value="<?php echo $ord1['brand'];?>"><?php echo $ord1['brand'];?></option> 

                                                       <?php

                                                       }
                                                       ?>   
                                                     </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="da-form-row">
                                         <label>Product<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                <div class="da-form-item small">
                                                    <select name="prod" id="prod" onChange="retrievequantity(this.value)">
                                                    <option value="">--- select product  ---</option>
                                                    </select>



                                                </div>
                                            </div> 
                                           <div class="da-form-row">
                                         <label>Customer name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                <div class="da-form-item small">
                                                    <input type="text" name="customername"  id="customername" class="required char" value=""/>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="da-form-row">
                                         <label>Phone Number<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                <div class="da-form-item small">
                                                    <input type="text" name="phonenumber"  id="phonenumber" class="required number" value=""/>
                                                </div>
                                            </div> 

                                            <div class="da-form-row">
                                         <label>Email<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                <div class="da-form-item small">
                                                    <input type="text" name="email"  id="email" class="required email" value=""/>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="da-form-row">
                                         <label>Address<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                <div class="da-form-item small">
                                              <textarea name="address" id="address" class="required"></textarea>

                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                          <div class="da-form-row">
                                         <label>Quantity<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                <div class="da-form-item small">

                                                    <select name="quantity" id="quantity">
                                                    <option value=""> --- select Quantity--- </option>
                                                     </select>

                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                          <div class="da-form-row">
                                         <label>Total Price<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                <div class="da-form-item small">
                                                    <input type="text" name="pri" id="pri" class="required number" value=""/>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>


                                          <div class="da-form-row">
                                         <label>Courier<span class="required"></span></label>
                                                <div class="da-form-item small">
                                                    <!--<input type="text" name="courier"  id="courier" class="required" value=""/>-->
                                                    <select name="courier" id="courier">
                                                    <option value=""> ---select courier --- </option>
                                                    <?php
                                                    $ord=mysql_query("select courier_name from courier_info");

                                                    while($ord1=mysql_fetch_array($ord))
                                                    {

                                                    ?>  
                                                       <option value="<?php echo $ord1['courier_name'];?>"><?php echo $ord1['courier_name'];?></option> 

                                                       <?php

                                                       }
                                                       ?>   
                                                     </select>

                                                </div>
                                            </div> 

                                             <div class="da-form-row">
                                         <label>Channel<span class="required"></span></label>
                                                <div class="da-form-item small">
                                                    <!--<input type="text" name="channel"  id="channel" class="required" value=""/>-->
                                                    <select name="channel" id="channel">
                                                    <option value=""> --- select channel ---</option>
                                                    <?php
                                                    $ord=mysql_query("select channel from channel_info");

                                                    while($ord1=mysql_fetch_array($ord))
                                                    {

                                                    ?>  
                                                       <option value="<?php echo $ord1['channel'];?>"><?php echo $ord1['channel'];?></option> 

                                                       <?php

                                                       }
                                                       ?>   
                                                     </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                          <div class="da-button-row">
                                            <input type="submit"  name="submit"  value="submit" onclick="confirm()" class="da-button red" />

                                        </div>

                                       </fieldset>
                                    </form>

  </div>
            <!-- End of .grid_4 --> </div>
            </div>

     <script>
function retrievedata(data)
{
var option_html = "";

<?php
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT distinct brand,product_name FROM stock_info");
while($ord1=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{

?>
    if(data == '<?php echo $ord1['brand']; ?>')
    {
        option_html += "<option><?php echo $ord1['product_name']; ?></option>";
        /*alert(option_html);*/
    }
<?php
}

?>
var par = document.getElementById("prod");
par.innerHTML = "<option>--- select product ---</option>"+option_html;
}

function retrievequantity(product)
{
var option_quantity_html = "";

<?php
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT product_name, quantity_in_stock FROM stock_info");
while($ord2=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$i=1;
?>
    if(product == '<?php echo $ord2['product_name']; ?>')
    {
        <?php
        while($i<=intval($ord2['quantity_in_stock'])){?>
        option_quantity_html += "<option><?php echo $i++; ?></option>";
        <?php }?>
    }
<?php
}

?>

var par = document.getElementById("quantity");
par.innerHTML = option_quantity_html;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? The best way would be to submit your order with an ajax request and if the order is inserted correctly, you have an ajax event that is fired after the ajax request is done successfully. On that event you would fire your dialog

Comment: actually, the problem is updating the order_id

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="btn" name="btn" onclick='return add_data()'/>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function add_data() 
{
    var ans = confirm("Want to add more?");
    if(ans)
    { return true; // ur code for add new data again }
    else
    { return false; }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use :

```
//Retrieve last order ID inserted
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

And store it in a $_SESSION or $_COOKIE

Answer (score 0):

You could save that `order_id` in the php `$_SESSION` variable and check if that exists there. Then use that `$orderId` within the next order.
I would also suggest to refactor your code and add [jQuery](http://jquery.com) for frontend and maybe put your code into a php class.

Comment: updating order_id in the table is the biggest problem ,as it is auto incremented fied

Comment: Reading from your description, a `single booking` is an order with  a unique `order_id` and some data (products etc.). When you want to add another order or booking, you want to keep the same `order_id` correct ? If all of the above is correct then you would need to modify your database table structure to have a separate column for a unique `order_id` and maybe add a column called `booking_id` ?

Comment: i have created a new table with the same structure where order_id is not unique and am inserting into it